# Imported function not doing what it's supposed to when running jest

Tags: javascript, import, export

DATA STORE FILE:

```
let data = {
  users: [],
  channels: [],

};
// Use get() to access the data
function getData() {
  return data;
}

// Use set(newData) to pass in the entire data object, with modifications made
function setData(newData) {
  data = newData;
}

export { getData, setData };
```

---

clearV1() FILE:

```
import { getData, setData } from './dataStore';


function clearV1() {

  let data = {
    users: [],
    channels: [],
  };

  setData(data);
  return {};
}

export { clearV1 };
```

When running the clearV1() function in another, it does not clear the data store. For example:
authRegisterV1 creates a user and adds them to the data store
channelCreateV1 creates a channel and adds it to the data store

```
authRegisterV1('test1@gmail.com','test123','Firt','Last');

clearV1()

authRegisterV1('test2@gmail.com','test123','Firt','Last');

expected output: 
{
      users: [
        {
          uId: 1,
          email: 'test2@gmail.com',
          password: 'test123',
          nameFirst: 'Firt',
          nameLast: 'Last',
          handle: 'firtlast0',
          permissionId: 2
        }
      ],
      channels: [],
}

wrong output:
{
      users: [
        {
          uId: 1,
          email: 'test1@gmail.com',
          password: 'test123',
          nameFirst: 'Firt',
          nameLast: 'Last',
          handle: 'firtlast',
          permissionId: 1
        },
        {
          uId: 2,
          email: 'test2@gmail.com',
          password: 'test123',
          nameFirst: 'Firt',
          nameLast: 'Last',
          handle: 'firtlast0',
          permissionId: 2
        }
      ],
      channels: [],
}
```

I believe the implementation of the clearV1() function is correct, what other possible reason could there be for this error? I imported all the used functions into the test file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem your facing is the fact that you created `data` inside of `./dataStore`, and thus, it does not exist in `clearV1()` file. Another way to put is, when you made the data variable initially, it was made in `./dataStore` and only exists there. So it makes a new variable instead of updating the existing one.

Another problem is, you are trying to using `let data = [value]`. `let` creates the variable just inside of the function you called it in, ignoring any variables on the outside. As a rule of thumb in javascript, when updating an existing variable, use `[name] = [value]`.

If you want to learn more, here's the MDN docs for [import statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [let statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).